# Ordenación de las filas en verificación de datos DbUnit

Tags: java

Estoy intentado realizar una verificación de los datos DbUnit tras un insert  entre un archivo xml (dataset) y una tabla de la base de datos. He ordenado ambas tablas por "ID" y después ignoro dicha columna para realizar la comparación puesto que su valor es auto incremental y no sé cuál es el de la nueva inserción. El código es el siguiente en base a la documentación DbUnit:

```
IDataSet databaseDataSet = getConnection().createDataSet();
ITable actualTable = databaseDataSet.getTable("TYPES");

FlatXmlDataSetBuilder flatXmlDataSetBuilder = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder();
flatXmlDataSetBuilder.setColumnSensing(true);
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(xml);
IDataSet expectedDataset = flatXmlDataSetBuilder.build(fileInputStream);
ITable expectedTable = expectedDataset.getTable("TYPES");

SortedTable sortedExpected = new SortedTable(expectedTable, new String[]{"ID"});
sortedExpected.setUseComparable(true);

SortedTable sortedActual = new SortedTable(actualTable, new String[]{"ID"});
sortedActual.setUseComparable(true);

Assertion.assertEqualsIgnoreCols(sortedExpected, sortedActual, new String[] {"ID"});
```

XML actual:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
<TYPES ID="7" PARENTESCO="Cónyuge" USUARIOMOD="W"/>
<TYPES ID="6" PARENTESCO="Hijo/a" USUARIOMOD="q"/>
<TYPES ID="3" PARENTESCO="Hijo/a" USUARIOMOD="q"/>
<TYPES ID="1" PARENTESCO="Padre/Madre  politíco/a" USUARIOMOD="W"/>
<TYPES ID="4" PARENTESCO="Hijo/a" USUARIOMOD="q"/>
<TYPES ID="5" PARENTESCO="Cónyuge" USUARIOMOD="W"/>
<TYPES ID="1051" PARENTESCO="Primo" USUARIOMOD="A"/>
</dataset>
```

XML expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
<TYPES ID="7" PARENTESCO="Cónyuge" USUARIOMOD="W"/>
<TYPES ID="6" PARENTESCO="Hijo/a" USUARIOMOD="q"/>
<TYPES ID="3" PARENTESCO="Hijo/a" USUARIOMOD="q"/>
<TYPES ID="1" PARENTESCO="Padre/Madre  politíco/a" USUARIOMOD="W"/>
<TYPES ID="4" PARENTESCO="Hijo/a" USUARIOMOD="q"/>
<TYPES ID="5" PARENTESCO="Cónyuge" USUARIOMOD="W"/>
<TYPES PARENTESCO="Primo" USUARIOMOD="A"/>
</dataset>
```

La última fila es la insertada. No especifico el campo ID puesto que no sé qué valor toma.

Después de ordenar:

sortedActual:

```
<TYPES ID="1" PARENTESCO="Padre/Madre  politíco/a" USUARIOMOD="W"/>
<TYPES ID="1051" PARENTESCO="Primo" USUARIOMOD="A"/>
<TYPES ID="3" PARENTESCO="Hijo/a" USUARIOMOD="q"/>
<TYPES ID="4" PARENTESCO="Hijo/a" USUARIOMOD="q"/>
<TYPES ID="5" PARENTESCO="Cónyuge" USUARIOMOD="W"/>
<TYPES ID="6" PARENTESCO="Hijo/a" USUARIOMOD="q"/>
<TYPES ID="7" PARENTESCO="Cónyuge" USUARIOMOD="W"/>
```

sortedExpected:

```
<TYPES PARENTESCO="Primo" USUARIOMOD="A"/>
<TYPES ID="1" PARENTESCO="Padre/Madre  politíco/a" USUARIOMOD="W"/>
<TYPES ID="3" PARENTESCO="Hijo/a" USUARIOMOD="q"/>
<TYPES ID="4" PARENTESCO="Hijo/a" USUARIOMOD="q"/>
<TYPES ID="5" PARENTESCO="Cónyuge" USUARIOMOD="W"/>
<TYPES ID="6" PARENTESCO="Hijo/a" USUARIOMOD="q"/>
<TYPES ID="7" PARENTESCO="Cónyuge" USUARIOMOD="W"/>
```

La ordenación de las filas es incorrecta puesto que se ordenan como String y el campo ID es de tipo numérico, por lo tanto la comparación falla. Alguna idea sobre cómo ordenar las filas en orden creciente de ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opción A: Más directa

Al crear el `SortedTable`, en vez de pasar el nombre de columnas pasa un `Column[]` y especifica el orden:

```
new SortedTable(expectedTable, new String[]{"ID"})
```

pasa a

```
new SortedTable(expectedTable, new Column[]{
   new Column("ID", DataType.INTEGER)}) // o LONG o BIGINT o lo ques ea.
```

Lo que no tengo muy claro es que pasará si la tabla tiene el metadata incorrecto, igual tendrás que hacer `flatXmlDataSetBuilder.setMetadata()` para asegurarte que la tabla original reconoce la columna `ID` como entera.

---

Opción 2:

Implementa un `Comparator` y pásaselo al `SortedTable` con `setRowComparator`. Algo más de código, pero más sencilla conceptualmente.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, he probado la primera opción y sigue ordenando mal los registros. La segunda no puedo implementarla en este proyecto. Existe alguna otra solución?